# What are the frameworks available for Sprite management in Android 2.3.x?

Tags: android, gamekit

Can anyone point me to any sprite management frameworks that can be used for sprite management and animation on Android (2.3 onwards). I have seen there is an animation Class that is part of HoneyComb release (but that's for tablets only) .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try Andengine or Cocos2D-android